# Equivalent of macro EVT_SCROLLWIN and EVT_MOUSE_EVENTS when using dynamic event table instead of static one

Tags: c++, macros, wxwidgets

I am learning wxWidgets and i came across the following example that uses static event table:

```
EVT_SCROLLWIN(VScrollWindow::OnScroll)
EVT_MOUSE_EVENTS(VScrollWindow::OnMouse)
```

Now I want use dynamic event table using `Bind` but I could not find any macro corresponding the `EVT_SCROLLWIN` and `EVT_MOUSE_EVENTS` that can be used inside `Bind`. I also searched in the [documentation page](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_scroll_win_event.html) but there also it is written only that:

> `EVT_SCROLLWIN(func)`:
>
> Process all scroll events.

As we can see the above doesn't specify something like `wxEVT_SCROLLWIN`.

This is what I have tried:

```
Bind(/*what should come here*/, VScrollWindow::OnScroll, this);
Bind(/*what should come here*/, VScrollWindow::OnMouse, this);
```

**My question is** what should come in the comment part in the above snippet. Basically I want to have the same effect using `Bind` as was done using static event table.

Comment: @Kai, you already have an answer - just prepend the name with `wx`. Does it give you any trouble?

Comment: @Igor That won't work. Try adding the prefix `wx` before `EVT_SCROLLWIN` and `EVT_MOUSE_EVENTS` and you'll get error.

Answer (score 2):

`EVT_SCROLLWIN` and `EVT_MOUSE_EVENTS` are special event macros that handle all mouse or scroll events.  The idea was that in the handler method, you would check for all the event types you were interested in and handle them in sub-blocks.

```cpp
if ( ev.GetEventType() != wxEVT_MOTION )
{
...
}
else if ( ev.GetEventType() != wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN )
{...
```

There are no equivalent for those macros when using `Bind`. The only option is to bind handlers for the individual event types separately. For example:

```cpp
Bind(wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN, VScrollWindow::OnMouseLeftDown, this);
Bind(wxEVT_SCROLLWIN_THUMBTRACK, VScrollWindow::OnThumb, this);
...
```

It might seem like more work, but really you're just moving control flow for event handling from one long event handler to a series of `Bind` calls.